# How to compute distance in a GPX file?

Tags: java, gpx

I'm taking a beginner CS class and part of my homework is to code a GPX file reader that allows the user to select an option from a menu to show things like total distance, elevation gain and loss, etc. I've figured out how to have the user input the file and how to create the menu, but I'm unsure on how to read the file to grab the lat. and long. points. To my understanding (correct me if i'm wrong), you take the first coordinates and compute the distance between those first ones and the next set of coordinates, and then continue on and on until you reach the last coordinates in the file.

However, i'm having trouble pulling out the coordinates from the file itself, this is the code i'm working with right now just so you guys have an idea of what my skill level is at. I know it could be totally off but I'd really appreciate help in this, thank you!!

```
public static void distance(Scanner input) {
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String longcheck = input.nextLine();
        if (longcheck.equals("lon")) {
            double lon1 = input.nextDouble();
            double lat1 = input.nextDouble();
```

This next bit is what I have to compute the distance (I've tested it for another assignment and it works fine)

```
                lat1 = Math.toRadians(lat1);
                lon1 = Math.toRadians(lon1);
                lat2 = Math.toRadians(lat2);
                lon2 = Math.toRadians(lon2);

                double longdis = lon1 - lon2; //calculating longitudinal difference
                double angudis = Math.sin(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) + Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(longdis);
                angudis = Math.acos(angudis); //converted back to radians
                angudis = angudis * 6372.795; //multiplied by the radius of the Earth
                System.out.println("The distance between the two points is " + angudis + "kilometers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your actual output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post [mcve]. If the problem is reading from file, the distance computation is not relevant.

Comment: A GPX file uses an XML format. The easiest way to parse it is to use an XML parser (search for it).

Comment: @Henry thanks, I looked up about XML parsers and it's way ahead of what we're learning in class but i'll do my best to figure it out!